# Laravel 5.1 - When registering user App redirects to /dashboard but doesn't check if account is confirmed

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-authorization

When my users register in my app it automatically redirects them to `/dashboard` which is technically fine, but it isn't checking to see if the `confirmed` column in the database has a value of `1` or `0`, it's just logging in based on the username and password.

I will happily include code but right now I don't actually know what code you guys need to see.

I need it to check the `confirmed` column and if it's a `0`, not to log them in and throw and error.

thanks for any info,

Andy

Comment: I achieve this with `middleware`

Comment: I'm still new to Laravel @OliverQueen do you have any examples at all? I'm using basic middleware to stop unauthorised access to dashboard etc, but need a helping hand in this register redirect issue

Comment: Yeah, I'll show you mine in an answer...

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieve this by utilizing middleware:

My routes.php:

```
Route::get('home', ['middleware' => 'auth', function ()    {

    return "This is just an example";

}]);
```

My Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [

        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,

    ];
```

My Authenticate.php middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }  
        }

        $user = $this->auth->user();
        if (!$user->confirmed) {
            $this->auth->logout();
            return redirect()->guest('auth/login')->with('error', 'Please confirm your e-mail address to continue.');
        }

        if (!$user->type) {
            $this->auth->logout();
            return redirect()->guest('auth/login')->with('error', 'A user configuration error has occurred. Please contact an administrator for assistance.');
        }    

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I tried to cut this down as much as possible for you.

Comment: Nice one, this makes a lot of sense. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!